# Jekyll 3.0 beta on Window 7 - Permission Denied

Tags: jekyll

I had a 2.4 version of Jekyll running on my win7 machine to play with.  It was few months back.  Well, now I've upgraded to 3.0 beta.  I've done a "jekyll build"  When I run "jekyll serve" i'm getting the following error:

```
Configuration file: none
  Source: C:/Projects/Prototypes/Jekyll-Test-Site/_plugins
  Destination: C:/Projects/Prototypes/Jekyll-Test-Site/_plugins/_site
Incremental build: enabled
  Generating...
    done.
Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
  gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Projects/Prototypes/Jekyll-Test-Site/_plugins'
Configuration file: none
jekyll 3.0.0-beta1 | Error:  Permission denied - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:4000
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something small, but I can't find it.

Comment: You may just change another port: `bundle exec jekyll serve --port 8005`

Answer (score 1):

Using: `jekyll serve --trace`

I found that it appeared that Ruby was properly trying to spin up a socket, only to get an permission problem when trying to bind to the socket.  Jekyll defaults to port 4000.  I used a socket on localhost that I've use for another application (that wasn't running) and it spun up just fine. Make sure to pick a port that isn't being used.  To find out what ports are being used run: netstat -an

Comment: I was having the same issue on Jekyll 3.0.3. I was actually running apache and mysql server in parallel. When I stopped those services, jekyll automatically worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, because the version of `wdm` is low, you should update the wdm by using: `gem install wdm`
then, because the `port 4000` is occupied by other application, you should add a line `port:4001` (any other port that has not been occupied) to the document `_config.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your socket localhost:4000 is occupied. You can use  `netstat -a` to check it. If so, change another socket that is not occupied in the socket list. Good luck.